# Can a magus proc Enforcerer on a Spellstrike with Frostbite?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

The [Enforcer feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enforcer-combat) activates "Whenever you deal nonlethal damage with a **melee weapon**".

If a magus delivers [Frostbite](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/frostbite) through a weapon with their [Spellstrike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spellstrike-Su-), will it proc the Enforcer feat?

Comment: I've given this an edit to cut out the unnecessarily high amount of quotage and just linked to the feats in the d20pfsrd, and rephrased your question slightly. (Nothing wrong with quoting from the SRD, but considering you were just quoting a huge chunk in full without really needing to, we might as well just concentrate your question down to your actual question.) Does it still reflect what you're intending to ask? Also, is there a particular reason you chose Frostbite in particular, or is it just an example of a spell you might use?

Comment: @doppelgreener The spell *frostbite* specifically does nonlethal damage, necessary for the feat Enforcer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Would this benefit from referencing nonlethal damage spells in general with Frostbite as an example?

Comment: @doppelgreener Maybe? Thing is, the spell must *also* be a touch spell, so the combination of a touch spell that deals nonlethal damage is rare enough that if someone wants to bring in a different example, that should probably be his burden. Besides, maybe it's *supposed* to be this specific, and specific is preferred over general, after all.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Alright. Leaving this as just Frostbite sounds A-OK to me if the combination seems fairly unique. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener no prob with the "edit" :) I used Frostbite as example of a kind of touch spell that add a rider effect (nonlethal damage) and can be discarged through a weapon attack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Officially, this is unresolved; ask the GM

At the time of this writing, about 60 users had marked this exact question as a FAQ candidate in [this 2-year-old Paizo messageboard thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qp6i&page=1?Enforcer-Spellstrike-Frostbite). It can be argued both ways. To summarize those arguments:

- #### Yes, the feat [Enforcer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enforcer-combat) activates

  The magus has dealt nonlethal damage with his weapon, in much the same way the magus would have had he instead touched the target. The magus gains the benefit of the feat.
- #### No, the feat [Enforcer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enforcer-combat) doesn't activate

  The magus's weapon *delivers* the spell, and, if the weapon didn't deal nonlethal damage, then the feat Enforcer *can't* activate. The magus doesn't gain the benefit of the feat.

Both arguments are persuasive, perhaps explaining the lack of developer intervention.

Comment: I'm not understanding the bit about "explaining the lack of developer intervention".

Comment: @GuidingLight  That is, maybe the developers haven't weighed in on the topic because they're still debating the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of Enforcer and Spellstrike seems incompatible when considered closely, but I'd consult your GM for their interpretation. Enforcer specifies dealing the nonlethal damage with the **weapon**, whereas Spellstrike says the "melee attack deals its normal damage **as well as the effects of the spell.**" They are not necessarily the same damage source.

It may be worth noting that in the game I'm currently in, playing a Magus, someone has asked me if I was using this exact combination. So while it may, in all technicality, be incorrect, it's an idea floating around the PF community so it's probably functional.

Though I hate the "everyone's doing it so it must be right" excuse, I don't see why this combination wouldn't work. Frostbite is a rare example of nonlethal damage on a touch attack. It's mostly ranged, AoE or persistent effect spells like [Admonishing Ray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/admonishing-ray), [River of Wind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/river-of-wind) or [Cup of Dust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cup-of-dust) (respectively) that deal nonlethal damage. The fact that Frostbite can be used with Spellstrike is what would make this work, in contrast to other spells that deal nonlethal damage.

Comment: Though technically you could also use Admonishing Ray with Spellstrike with the right combination of Arcana, that's beside the point.